# Split String in ASCii

Tags: vba, string

I want to split many strings into its ASCII values.

```
Dim aoC(99), i As Integer    
Dim W As String

W="abcd"
For i = 1 To Len(W)
    aoC(i) = Asc(Mid(W, i, 1))
Next
```

Is there a faster method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Dim aoC() as Byte
aoC="abcd"
```

This will give you a byte array of low,high bytes for the 16 bit value for each character in the string.  For ascii values the high byte is 0.  So to iterate the aoC for the low byte only you would use something like

```
For myIndex = 0 to ubound(aoC) step 2
```

Use the locals window to see the raw data.